# Can matlab solve a system of more than two PDEs numerically?

Tags: matlab

I know that MATLAB can solve a system of 2 coupled PDEs using pdex4, however is there something similar that can solve a system of more coupled PDEs, say 6? The bigger system has the same structure (dependence on partial derivatives, boundary conditions, type of initial condition etc) as the system of 2 equations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With the [FEATool Matlab FEM toolbox](https://www.featool.com) you can set up and solve an arbitrary number of coupled PDEs.

Answer (score 2):

The function pdefun (that you pass as an input to pdepe) defines your system of equations and has the general form,

```
[c,f,s] = pdefun(x,t,u,dudx)
```

c, f, and s are coefficients in the PDE (see Eq. 1-3 [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html)). They can be column vectors to allow for any number of coupled equations. In the pdex4 example these vectors have 2 elements; in your case they would have 6.

Answer (score -1):

MATLABs Partial Differential Equation Toolbox allows you to solve systems of multiple equations. For coupling of source terms, you can solve the initial PDE for the source, then use that as an input for a second PDE model which will give the final results. More info can be found [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/pde.html)